# Wordpress - URL download with email form

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress page and a form. The form is generated by Contact Form 7 and [Email Before Download](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-before-download/). Currently it works like this:

`[email-download download_id="***" contact_form_id="***"]`

So when the user fills out the form, he gets the download link to the file. Can I add a download without a file? I want to just hide a URL behind this registration form. So when the user registers, he gets an email with the url, but there's no file, just a webpage.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like your form is generated from a plugin or a theme shortcode. In both case you need to hook inside the form submission to do that. But without knowing the pugin used or the theme function we can't really help you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using "[Email Before Download](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-before-download/faq/)"-wordpress plugin.
This plugin (v2.0 and newer) has an option to only email the link to the user;

```
[email-download download_id="***" contact_form_id="***" delivered_as="Send Email"]
```

**(EDIT)** To use an external link:

```
[email-download download_id="***" contact_form_id="***" file="http://www.google.com"]
```

Comment: Yes, I have been using this feature. The question is, whether I can make the download itself not a picture/file to download, but a url only. So if he fills the form out,he gets a url to a webpage, not to a file.

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-before-download/faq/), it looks like you can add "file"-option to point to an external URL.

`[email-download download_id="***" contact_form_id="***" file="http://www.google.com"]`

Comment: This is not working. If I use the file variable, why should I also include the download id? If I exclude the download ID, I get a blank page. If I include it, I get an empty delimiter error for strpos.

Comment: It sounds like this plugin isn't the ideal candidate for what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: That's why I'm asking, how to do this :D